# What is the percentage of my actual code inside qt app

Tags: c++, qt, cpu-usage

I am trying to understand the CPU usage of my c++ application developed with QT 5.12.9. I am using qt analyzer + perf on linux environment.

I am running the deployment remotely on a virtual 2-cores machine with ubuntu18.04 (release mode for sure)

From the flame graph (figure) I observed that my actual app makes 8% of the whole application execution!.

Is it most of the time qt behind the scenes working loops consuming? or how to interpret that only 8% holds my source code (3rd segment from left)?

[image: Flame graph- check 3rd segment from left]